# flutter : Textfield duplicates first data entry

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, textfield

I am creating an application where user can add their triggers. I am not sure what happens but everytime that I entry any data to the first textfield its duplicate to the next one. Users can add multiples textfields with a button.

This problem appear when I added a controller to the textfield.

This is the code -

```
children: List.generate(
                        totalTextField,
                        (index) => Row(children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                  width: 90,
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: _triggersController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      isDense: true,
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                      hintText: 'Add...',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                          color: Color.fromARGB(
                                              255, 194, 193, 193),
                                          fontSize: 13),
                                      filled: true,
                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              SizedBox(width: 5),
                              if (index == totalTextField - 1)
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                                    elevation: 2,
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
                                    minimumSize: Size(60, 24),
                                  ),
```

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHgAN.png)

thank you for your help guys

Comment: you can try to add a uniq `valueKey` to children widget. So the flutter know that the new one has created is a different widget to build.

Comment: maybe something like 
=> `Row( key: ValueKey(index.toString()) , 
children: [ // other widgets  ]`

Comment: hello pmatatias, i am quite new in programming, could you please tell how to do it?

Comment: i already give example on my comments. 

or maybe can you provide more code, what happends when you press the button?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when i press the button it create a new textfield with the same data as before, so for example if i write animals in the first textfield, the other textfields create with the button will have animals already inside

Comment: i see, 
then you need to declare controller inside the textfield

Comment: Its already declare you can see in the code its called _tiggerscontroller , so its giving me the same problem

Comment: i mean  like here `child: TextField( controller: TextEditingController() )`

Answer (score 0):

propably because you have `TextField` generated always with the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is Because all the TextFields are using just one controller

```
_triggersController
```

So when you change the text in one field all the fields will change their value too.

Generate a variable having list of controllers as well and then you can pass that controllers list inside your **TextField**

```
List<TextEditingController> allControllers =
          List.generate(totalTextField, (index) => TextEditingController());
```

And now pass the controller as well.

```
TextField(
         controller: allControllers[index],
         decoration: InputDecoration(
         isDense: true,
         contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
         hintText: 'Add...',
         hintStyle: TextStyle(
         fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
         color: Color.fromARGB(
         255, 194, 193, 193),
         fontSize: 13),
         filled: true,
         fillColor: Colors.white,
         ),
       )),
```

To use the controller to get the text back you can use

```
allControllers[1].text;
```

Comment: Hello Shree, is giving this error ' The instance member 'totalTextField' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression '

Comment: You can create an instance variable and assign the value inside the class constructor. Or you can create this variable inside the build widget